# Reinstalling Windows to Make MOBO and Memory LEDs Default

Tags: memory, motherboard, operating-systems, rgb

I’ve been trying to reset my motherboard and memory LEDs to default using MSI’s Mystic Light software, but every time I reboot, it loads to the same config, not the default settings I applied. Will doing a fresh install of Windows fix this?

Comment: How are you changing the led settings now, using some program probably? Does completely removing & reinstalling that program help? (OT, but why would you want a memory stick with built-in LED's, when you can just use separate [cheap] led's anyway? Sounds like an extra expense and more stuff to fail)

Comment: Uninstalling the program didn’t do anything. I’m assuming there are still saved files somewhere. But will reinstalling Windows help?

Comment: They're probably stored in the registry, or in a config file which isn't removed when you remove the application. Your best bet is to contact MSI support.

Comment: I don't know, you'd have to look into how the program saves the settings. Maybe it's the memory led's themselves that aren't accepting new settings, or something in the BIOS/EFI... and windows has a few different ways of reinstalling, refreshing,  etc, some of them probably don't erase every file on the drive

Comment: @spikey_richie So would a fresh install help? When I remove the app, it says there are still files left that can be removed manually, so does that mean installing Windows again would help?

Comment: If you formatted your drive first, sure.